# {genealogytree} How to draw multiple marriage without edge intersections

Tags: intersections, genealogytree

Could anybody give me a hint on how to draw the following situation (3 marriages) with no edge-intersection?
The example is taken from the [manual](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf), p. 233.
[image: 3 marriages]

Comment: welcome to the site -- please have a look at the answer below if it suits the requirement

Comment: @jsbibra thanks! It's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{genealogypicture}[template=signpost,
    after tree={
                \draw[red,ultra thick](wife)--++(0,-1)-|(hus2);
                \draw[blue,ultra thick]($(wife.south)+(-0.3,0)$)--++(0,-0.5)-|(hus3);   
            }]
    child[edges down by=2 of 4]{
        p{Husband1}
        g[id=wife]{Wife} c{Child1} c{Child2} c{Child3} c{Child4}
        union[edges up by=1 of 4]{ p[disconnect, id=hus2]{Husband2} }
        union[edges up by=1 of 4]{ p[disconnect, id=hus3]{Husband3} }
    }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```